# How do I use cor.test within foreach in R?

Tags: r, foreach, correlation

I'm not sure how to correct the code to run a cor.test within foreach. The code I have tried is below (prac3 is the name of the data frame I am working with). The variables I want to correlate are in columns.

```
cor.res<- foreach(i=seq_len(ncol(prac3)) %dopar% {
 d <- prac3[,i]
  correlation<- cor.test(d$x, d$y, method = "spearman")
  out <- c(correlation$estimate,correlation$p.value)
 }


 cor.res<- foreach(i=seq_len(ncol(prac3)) %dopar% {
  correlation<- cor.test(prac3[,i], prac3, method = "spearman")
  out <- c(correlation$estimate,correlation$p.value)
     }


 cor.res<- foreach(i=seq_len(ncol(prac3)) %dopar% {
 correlation<- cor.test(prac3[[i[1]]], prac3[[i[2]]], method = "spearman")
 out <- c(correlation$estimate,correlation$p.value)
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it.  The issue is that `cor.test()` wants two vectors.  So, rather than looping over a single variable (`I`) you probably want to get all pairs of variables. That said, `foreach` loops over a single index.  What I would do is to first make a data frame that has all the combinations first:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(foreach)
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- mtcars[,1:7]
eg <- expand.grid(row = 1:ncol(mtcars), col = 1:ncol(mtcars))
eg <- eg %>% filter(row < col)
```

Next, you can change the numbers to variable names in the following way:

```r
eg$row <- names(mtcars)[eg$row]
eg$col <- names(mtcars)[eg$col]
```

Now, you need to loop over all the rows of `eg`, where `eg[i,1]` will stand in for the first variable name and `eg[i,2]` will stand in for the second variable name.  We can use `tidy()` from the `broom` package to clean the results up a bit and then combine them with `rbind`:

```r
cor.res<- foreach(i=1:nrow(eg), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
  broom::tidy(cor.test(mtcars[, eg[i,1]], 
                       mtcars[, eg[i,2]], 
                       method="spearman")) %>% 
    mutate(row=eg[i,1], col=eg[i,2])
}

cor.res
#> # A tibble: 21 × 7
#>    estimate statistic  p.value method                        alter…¹ row   col  
#>       <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>                         <chr>   <chr> <chr>
#>  1   -0.911    10425. 4.69e-13 Spearman's rank correlation … two.si… mpg   cyl  
#>  2   -0.909    10415. 6.37e-13 Spearman's rank correlation … two.si… mpg   disp 
#>  3    0.928      395. 2.28e-14 Spearman's rank correlation … two.si… cyl   disp 
#>  4   -0.895    10337. 5.09e-12 Spearman's rank correlation … two.si… mpg   hp   
#>  5    0.902      536. 1.87e-12 Spearman's rank correlation … two.si… cyl   hp   
#>  6    0.851      813. 6.79e-10 Spearman's rank correlation … two.si… disp  hp   
#>  7    0.651     1902. 5.38e- 5 Spearman's rank correlation … two.si… mpg   drat 
#>  8   -0.679     9160. 1.94e- 5 Spearman's rank correlation … two.si… cyl   drat 
#>  9   -0.684     9186. 1.61e- 5 Spearman's rank correlation … two.si… disp  drat 
#> 10   -0.520     8294. 2.28e- 3 Spearman's rank correlation … two.si… hp    drat 
#> # … with 11 more rows, and abbreviated variable name ¹​alternative
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>